# Web App after deploying react in an iframe differently

Tags: google-apps-script

I have developed two web apps with google app script (I execute as me  and everyone even anonymous is allowed to access). Both have the complete same settings when I deploy it. In the `doGet` they are coded the same way:

```
var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("XXX")
 .evaluate()
 .setTitle(constData.getTitel()) //TODO: Text in const??
 .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
 html.addMetaTag(
   "viewport",
   "width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no"
 );
 html = html.setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL);
```

But when I implement it in an iframe on a HTML page I got two different behaviours. In one web app it is doing what it should. In the other I get authorization issues. When I look on the console the error I get is: "'X-Frame-Options' to 'deny'" But that shouldn`t be as you can see in the code before. Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: What happens if you open both webapps in a incognito window?(not in a iframe)

Comment: Do you use in both cases the `exec` and not `dev` url?